# clear compare list items rest api

Tags: magento2, rest-api

I'm building rest API to clear compare items list

here is code I'm using

```
  /**
* @api
* 
* @return int
*/
public function clearItems(){
    $userType = $this->userContext->getUserType();
    $id = $this->userContext->getUserId();

    if($userType === UserContextInterface::USER_TYPE_CUSTOMER){
        $this->collection->setCustomerId($id);
    }
    else if($userType === UserContextInterface::USER_TYPE_GUEST){
        $this->collection->setVisitorId($id);
    }
    $this->collection->setCustomerId($id);

    $this->collection->clear();

    return $id;
}
```

but it's deleted only from database and stay in the store. and when open the compare list from the store it returned again to database
and returned id is differ from the logged in user id

Answer (score 1):

Please update your function like below.

```
public function __construct(
  -------
  \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\Compare $compareHelper,
  -------
) {
     -----
     $this->compareHelper = $compareHelper;
     -----
 }
public function clearItems(){
$userType = $this->userContext->getUserType();
$id = $this->userContext->getUserId();

if($userType === UserContextInterface::USER_TYPE_CUSTOMER){
    $this->collection->setCustomerId($id);
}
else if($userType === UserContextInterface::USER_TYPE_GUEST){
    $this->collection->setVisitorId($id);
}
$this->collection->setCustomerId($id);

$this->collection->clear();
$this->compareHelper->calculate();
return $id;
}
```

I hope it'll work for you.

Comment: what does this line do $this->compareHelper->calculate();?
I've checked this function but didn't understand why to use it

Comment: it'll update update compare product collection which is in section or customer data.

Comment: that's working for only one customer. it keeps seeing the id of the first logged in customer only